Adding cell values, specific to each page, to each header
I'm trying to get my cover sheet header to display "Schedule", and each sheet's header after to display the date displayed in cell "a6", which is in cell "a6" on each sheet. The code I've been working on will only display 1 sheet's cell value  ("schedule", from the cover sheet) across all sheets. I need each sheet to pull from it's own cell "a6" and display the value in the header. How can I accomplish this?
Sub printless()
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    Dim wkst As Worksheet
        For Each wkst In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
            With wkst.PageSetup
                .CenterHeader = "&B&36" & Range("a6").Value ''''''BOLD/SIZE36, PULLS VALUE FROM CELL A6 AND PUT IS IN HEADER
                .PrintArea = "$a$6:$bb$108"
                .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
                .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
                .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.6)
                .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
                .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
                .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
                .CenterHorizontally = True
                .CenterVertically = False
                .Orientation = xlPortrait
                .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
                .Zoom = 46
            End With
        Next wkst
            With Worksheets("Cover Sheet").PageSetup
                .CenterHeader = "&B&36" & Range("a6").Value
                .PrintArea = "$b$1:$ac$52"
                .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
                .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
                .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(1)
                .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
                .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
                .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
                .CenterHorizontally = True
                .CenterVertically = False
                .Orientation = xlPortrait
                .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
                .Zoom = 75
            End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    ActiveWorkbook.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False
End Sub


Qualify all objects in this case ranges with worksheets i.e.  ... wkst.Range("A6").Value. Also, loop through the correct collection i.e. since you have declared wkst as a worksheet, use ...In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets. If this code is in the workbook whose worksheets are being printed, replace ActveWorkbook with ThisWorkbook.

Print Workbook

The key issues with your code are covered in your comments.
You could improve by using the following:

Sub printless()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ' If it isn't, reference the workbook by name or use 'ActiveWorkbook'.

    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    
    Dim wkst As Worksheet
    
    For Each wkst In wb.Worksheets
        With wkst.PageSetup
            Select Case wkst.Name
                Case "Cover Sheet"
                    .CenterHeader = "&B&36" & wkst.Range("A6").Value
                    .PrintArea = "$b$1:$ac$52"
                    .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
                    .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
                    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(1)
                    .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
                    .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
                    .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
                    .CenterHorizontally = True
                    .CenterVertically = False
                    .Orientation = xlPortrait
                    .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
                    .Zoom = 75
                Case Else
                    .CenterHeader = "&B&36" & wkst.Range("A6").Value
                    .PrintArea = "$a$6:$bb$108"
                    .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
                    .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
                    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.6)
                    .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
                    .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
                    .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
                    .CenterHorizontally = True
                    .CenterVertically = False
                    .Orientation = xlPortrait
                    .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
                    .Zoom = 46
            End Select
        End With
    Next wkst
    
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    
    wb.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False

End Sub


If the differences of the PageSetup arguments between the Cover Sheet and the rest of the sheets are final, you could shorten the code in the following way:

Sub printless()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ' If it isn't, reference the workbook by name or use 'ActiveWorkbook'.

    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    
    Dim wkst As Worksheet
    
    For Each wkst In wb.Worksheets
        With wkst.PageSetup
            .CenterHeader = "&B&36" & wkst.Range("A6").Value
            .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
            .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
            .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
            .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
            .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
            .CenterHorizontally = True
            .CenterVertically = False
            .Orientation = xlPortrait
            .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
            Select Case wkst.Name
                Case "Cover Sheet"
                    .PrintArea = "$b$1:$ac$52"
                    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(1)
                    .Zoom = 75
                Case Else
                    .PrintArea = "$a$6:$bb$108"
                    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.6)
                    .Zoom = 46
            End Select
        End With
    Next wkst
    
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    
    wb.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False

End Sub

